# Flex Mobile UI components — dealing with weird size

Tags: apache-flex

Flex Mobile project

I am setting Button's width like this:

```
prevBtn.width = (stage.stageWidth/2)-15
trace(prevBtn.width,stage.stageWidth)
```

«225 480» — says output panel, which is completely right;
but that button looks bigger than should — it is 340px wide.

Ok, I got this: something has its `scaleX` set to 1,5. I tried

```
var a:Object = prevBtn;
while(a!=null){
    trace(a.scaleX)
    a = a.parent;
}
```

and ­- of course ­- got this in output:

```
1
1
1
1
1.5
1
```

TL;DR: **how do I set my button's width to "50%-15px"?**

Comment: Are you setting the applicationDPI property in the main application instance?  I have found that causes a lot of sizing issues.

Comment: @Reboog711 yes, I found that dpi in application was set to 160 and I was simulated the 240dpi device. I fixed that, look at the answer below if interested.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I got this.

An idea was simple. I needed two buttons to have distance between them equal to distance between each and screen border.
For now, I use this code to automatically set widths:

```
<s:Button id="prevBtn" left="10" bottom="10" width="{this.width/2-prevBtn.x*1.5}" />
<s:Button id="nextBtn" right="10" bottom="10" width="{this.width/2-prevBtn.x*1.5}"/>
```

I don't know is it a good practice or not, but it works. Data binding rocks.

omg my English...